# Extract particular data from a field

Tags: php, mysql, filemaker

Used ODBC, I'm connecting filemaker to a mysql database.  Inside a mysql database record I have a single field that looks like this...

```
[{"id":"1","value":"Jonny Miller"},{"id":"2","value":"22"},{"id":"3","value":"1"}]
```

and the other fields in all the records are the same.


I would like to separate the 'id', 'value', 'Jonny Miller' etc... but don't know how to go about it.  Please can you let me know what I need to do or point me to somewhere, where I can see how to do it?
Thanks for your help
 Stef

Comment: you can use json_decode() and looping through it can retrieve data

Comment: Are you trying to parse the data using filemaker scripting or json?

Comment: Hi I was hoping I could use Execute MySQL in filemaker to do it but I'll try the json script - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`json_decode()`**](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

```
<?php
$str='[{"id":"1","value":"Jonny Miller"},{"id":"2","value":"22"},{"id":"3","value":"1"}]';
$a=json_decode($str,true);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!function_exists('json_decode'))
{
    function json_decode($json)
    {
        $comment = false;
        $out = '$x=';
        for ($i=0; $i<strlen($json); $i++)
        {
            if (!$comment)
            {
                if (($json[$i] == '{') || ($json[$i] == '['))
                    $out .= ' array(';
                else if (($json[$i] == '}') || ($json[$i] == ']'))
                    $out .= ')';
                else if ($json[$i] == ':')
                    $out .= '=>';
                else
                    $out .= $json[$i];
            }
            else
                $out .= $json[$i];
            if ($json[$i] == '"' && $json[($i-1)]!="\\")
                $comment = !$comment;
        }
        eval($out . ';');
        return $x;
    }
}

$str = '[{"id":"1","value":"Jonny Miller"},{"id":"2","value":"22"},{"id":"3","value":"1"}]';

$str = json_decode($str);

foreach ($str as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['id'] . " " . $value['value'] . "<br>";
}
```

**NOTE:** I've posted **json_decode** function as well, because it is no longer available in new versions of php ( also not supported in old versions )

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to parse the returned data using FileMaker. FileMaker does not natively support json parsing (to my extreme frustration :P). You can access the data with some good ol' fashion text parsing. I wrote this let statement in extreme detail (i.e. you can compact a lot of it into fewer steps, but this let statement shows each individual step separately so it's easier to learn (I think)):

```
Let ( [ 
    input              = $currentValue;
    key                = "id"; // Change this to the key you want to pull the value for
    keyStartPosition   = Position (input ; key ; 0 ; 1 );
    valueStartPosition = Position ( input ; "\"" ; keyStartPosition ; 2 );
    valueEndPosition   = Position ( input ;  "\"" ; valueStartPosition ; 2 );
    value              = Middle (input ; valueStartPosition + 1 ; valueEndPosition - valueStartPosition - 1)
 ]; 
    value 
)
```

Using this code, you can the write a script that "explodes" the json into return delimited values:

```
Substitute ( Get ( ScriptParameter )  ; "},{" ; ¶ )
```

You can then loop through each of the values and extract the value for the give id you specify in the let statement. Unfortunately I can't paste the FileMaker script code as a code block in here, but here's an image of the script you would use:

[image: Parsing json data in filemaker]

I believe there are also plugins that you could use to parse json, but this will get it done as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I should also add that this kind of parsing only works for json data that is not nested. If you have nested data you'd be better of looking for a json plugin for filemaker.

Comment: This is great, thanks I'll give it a go and let you know how I get on. - Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are various custom function libraries for parsing JSON structures in FileMaker. You'll need FileMaker Pro Advanced to integrate them into your solution. A quick Google search resulted in http://www.modularfilemaker.org/2013/08/json/.